# Cantor's Normal Form and Aleph_1

Tags: set-theory, ordinal-numbers

The Cantor Normal Form Theorem states that every ordinal $\alpha > 0$ can be uniquely expressed in the form $$\omega^{\beta_1}k_1 + \omega^{\beta_2}k_2 + \dots + \omega^{\beta_n}k_n$$ for some $n \ge 1$, positive integers $k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n$ and ordinals $\alpha \ge \beta_1 > \beta_2 > \dots > \beta_n$.

If I understand this correctly, then every countable ordinal's Cantor Normal Form is a finite-degree polynomial in $\omega$. My reasoning is that if $\beta$ is infinite, then $\omega^{\beta}$ is uncountable. This must be incorrect because it would imply that there are only countably many countable ordinals. Since $\aleph_1$ is the set of all countable ordinals and is uncountable, this is a contradiction.

My main question is where did I go wrong? If every countable set can't be written as a polynomial in $\omega$, what is a counter-example?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: No, exponentiation here is in the ordinal sense, it is not cardinal exponentiation. This is defined so $\alpha^\beta=\sup\{\alpha^\gamma\mid\gamma<\beta\}$ when $\beta$ is limit. But this easily gives (by an inductive argument) that $\alpha^\beta$ is countable if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are countable.

Comment: Well, $\omega^\omega = \sup \{\omega^n | n \in \omega \}$ but it is not countable.  What am I missing?

Comment: $\omega^\omega$ is countable, as is any countable limit or countable ordinals.

Comment: @Emily: ...it's a countable union of countable sets

Comment: $\omega^\omega$ here does not mean the set of functions from $\omega$ to $\omega$, rather here it means the set of polynomials in $\omega$ of finite degree with integer coefficients.

Comment: By definition, every ordinal is the set of all smaller ordinals.
And Cantor Normal Form ordinals are ordered lexicographically.
To be smaller than $\omega^\omega$ simply requires a leading term of smaller, and hence finite, degree (and any finite coefficient).

Comment: Oh, I see that Andres Caicedo was correct and I am confusing cardinal and ordinal arithmetic. I knew I must have been missing something. Thank you all!

Comment: You may also find the following discussions on math.SE useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109206/how-is-epsilon-0-countable/109245#109245 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83204/how-far-do-known-ordinal-notations-span/83209#83209

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the many comments, the issue is confusing ordinal and cardinal arithmetic. The number of such expressions that yield countable ordinals is uncountable, as it should be. This is because the $\beta$ can range over all countable ordinals (of which there $\aleph_1$ many). Thank you to all commenters for replying so quickly.